# Unable to boot Raspbian on QEMU

Tags: kernel, virtualization

recently I have a problem emulating Raspbian on QEMU for a school project.
The teacher provides me a guide, but when I start the qemu emulation appear this error and the emulation stopped.
This is the command: `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -dtb versatile-pbbuster. dtb -kernel kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -drive file=2020-02-13- raspbian-buster-lite.img,format=raw -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -serial stdio -no-reboot -k it`

And the error: [Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoa9G.png)
P.S I'm in Windows 10

Thanks to all.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Raspbian is not an official Ubuntu Flavor - [see here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for a detailed list.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Ah, sorry i didn't know

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the disk image exists. I think the space in your command is the issue

```
-drive file=2020-02-13- raspbian-buster-lite.img,
```

Should be

```
-drive file=2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite.img
```

Hope this is it

Comment: I fixed, but same problem

Comment: What appears in the log?